# C++ Arduino Slow serial communications

Tags: c++, serial-port, arduino, processing

I have a gyroscope (MPU6050) attached to my Arduino UNO. I have written a Processing script to read the serial data(get the angles) from the Gyroscope and its working fine. 
Now I would like to integrate it with a C++ OpenCV project. I use this tutorial class for serial communications: http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/CPPWindows

However, the serial communications is very slow, the 256 char array is filled in around 1.5 seconds. Thats around 170 chars/sec = 1.36 kbps.

So the question is: If the serial port works fast for Processing how come it is much slower using C++? Is there any alternative way for reading the gyroscope data to C++?

Here is the function which is triggered after each frame I capture from the webcam to get the serial data

```
int Serial::ReadandClose(char *buffer, unsigned int nbChar, const char* portName) 
{ 

     wchar_t wtext[20];
 mbstowcs(wtext, portName, strlen(portName)+1);//Plus null
 LPWSTR PortSpecifier = wtext;

 DCB dcb; 
 int retVal; 
 BYTE Byte; 
 DWORD dwBytesTransferred; 
 DWORD dwCommModemStatus; 

 HANDLE hPort = CreateFile( 
 PortSpecifier, 
GENERIC_READ, 
 0, 
 NULL, 
 OPEN_EXISTING, 
 0, 
 NULL 
 ); 
if (!GetCommState(hPort,&dcb)) 
 return 0x100; 
 dcb.BaudRate = CBR_115200; 
 dcb.ByteSize = 8; //8 data bits 
 dcb.Parity = NOPARITY; //no parity 
 dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT; //1 stop 

 if (!SetCommState(hPort,&dcb)) 
 return 0x100; 
  SetCommMask (hPort, EV_RXCHAR | EV_ERR); //receive character event 
 WaitCommEvent (hPort, &dwCommModemStatus, 0); //wait for character 

 if (dwCommModemStatus & EV_RXCHAR) 
     {
         clock_t begin =clock();
    ReadFile (hPort, buffer, 256, &dwBytesTransferred, 0);
    clock_t end = clock();
    double elapsed_secs = double(end-begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout<<elapsed_secs<<endl;
 }
else if (dwCommModemStatus & EV_ERR) 
 retVal = 0x101; 

 CloseHandle(hPort); 
 return dwBytesTransferred; 
    }
```

Comment: I didn't work with Arduino, but having spent some time with programming similar devices, I would suggest you try the same without dividing and calculating `elapsed_secs`. Maybe its not the main problem, but it may make a difference.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but actually measuring the time doesnt really consume that much, I included this time measurement code to show that im measuring the time of ReadFile function only and not the whole opening and closing processes. Appreciate your help though

Comment: @user3791279 maybe it is not actually sending the char array, you said that this was triggered after visual processing, maybe it's just visual processing taking a long time and then sending you the data? Also is it necessary to check the comm state every time? You may want to try reading for a different sensor which takes less time to read and see if this is the problem.

Comment: Actually the same hardware works with another software (Processing) so the arduino is definately sending chars, I have measured the frame rate with and without serial communications and obviously the large chunk of time is spent in the serial communication and not the image processing (which should actually be the other way around)

Comment: You open and close the port continually?  Why would you do that?

Comment: @MartinJames Opening and closing doesnt really take that much time compared to the readfile function... if you check elapsed_secs is 1.5 seconds JUST for the ReadFile function... im wondering if thats a normal rate

Comment: @user3791279 can you try reading less data (for example 1 char only) and test the results?